# Angled div shape

Tags: html, rotation, nav

Hi there a rather silly question I would like to **angle my div 45 degr** without the content rotating as can be seen the blue is an image which has the correct angle. but the div does not and because of this the on over color change looks wrong as it is not angled. **i have tried a few example but content always gets angled as well**.
***how could i achieve this?*** thanks in advance for any suggestions.

[image: angled nav bar]

HTML:

```
       <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">   
       <a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>    
      <a href="#news">News</a>
      <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
      <a href="#about">About</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction1();">&#9776;</a>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
    .topnav a {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  transform: skewY(-45deg);
}
```

Comment: ... please post come code

Comment: I have tried both of your suggestions it works and gives the angle but not the effect i am looking for with the on hover unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Here you go. The size of the triangle is determined by the border settings. Just insert this element after the a.about in your code.

```css
#triangle {
 width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 100px solid red;
 border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
```

here's the settings for each direction:

```
top-left: border-top and border-right
top-right: border-top and border-left
bottom-left: border-bottom and border-right
bottom-right: border-bottom and border-left
```